# Problems with cart and pages on _s theme

Tags: theme-development, formatting, troubleshooting

I recently took over managing this website [Berman Instruments](https://bermaninstruments.com/), one of our clients. They claim that it the cart was working until June.  This is a 2 part problem.

In this scenario, an unregistered user comes to the site, puts products in the cart, clicks on the cart then checkout, they are prompted to login or register on the My Account page. The formatting of this page is no longer correct. The second part of this problem is, once a new user completes registering, clicks on the cart, the cart empties.

I have updated the plugins and have been in touch with Flywheels, WooCommerce, and Gravity multiple times trying to resolve this issue. My last contact with WooCommerce support told me that the underscores theme is out of date. I read on **Stack Exchange** ***"you're not supposed to update Underscores.** There isn't really even anything to update. At this point it has become your theme and doesn't exist on its own."*

I have also spent some time searching for help on Git Hub and Stack Exchange. Can anyone offer some advise?

This image shows the formatting issue on the My Account page
[image]

Comment: If possible, revert back to the version you inherited - old plugin versions etc. so you can confirm whether everything works with that version. Most hosts keep backups and good devs ensure backups are available whether it's through the host or otherwise. If everything works, you can update one thing at a time until you find out what caused the break. And if not, you have evidence that it was already broken. They're correct that Underscores is just a starter theme that you customize and is then not updateable.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll contact Flywheels.